# Как передать с функции значения?

Tags: c++

Я делаю, так сказать, мини-игру, столкнулся с ошибкой, есть магазин, мне нужно вернуть значения, которые я передаю, вот пример кода (не весь):

```
#include 

using namespace std;

struct items {
    string name;
    int cost;
};

int trader (int strength_trader, int hp_trader, int money_trader) {
    items sword;
    sword.cost = 20;
    sword.name = "New sword";
    cout << "What u want to buy?" << endl;
            cout << "1." << sword.name << endl;
            cout << "4.Nothing" << endl;
            cin >> buy ;
            switch (buy){
                case 1:
                    money_trader = money_trader - sword.cost;
                    if ( money_trader < 0) {
                        system("cls");
                        cout << "U dont have enough money!" << endl;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        system("cls");
                        cout << "New sword" << endl;
                        strength_trader = strength_trader + 5;
                        cout << "Ur hp is: " << hp_trader << endl;
                        cout << "Ur attack is: " << strength_trader << endl;
                        cout << " " << endl;
                        cout << " " << endl;
                        break;
                    }
```

Все значения трейдера передаются с другой функции.
Вот как мне, например, вернуть значения strength_trader, или есть какая-нибудь команда, которая позволит записать в переменную другой функции значение этой переменой. Я сначала поменял тип функции с void на int, попробовал return strength_trader, но оно не работало, если нужны ещё фрагменты кода пишите, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: "пробывал return strength_trader, но оно не работало" - что значит не работало? Значит в ветку где return strength_trader не попадало

Comment: Изначально это return strength_trader был в 1 кейсе, но я его оттуда забрал, если его там поставить и так скажем купить что то, то ты мог сделать только 1 покупку, и я его вынес оттуда

Comment: Попробывал перенести назад, все равно не пашет, ну может и пашет оно скорее всего возваращает, но мне нужно записать значения ну другую переменную которая находится уже в другой функцие

Comment: Вы точку останова поставьте на входе функции и отлаживайте по шагам

Answer (score -1):

Проблема решена, я просто создал глобальную переменную, через неё все сделал

Comment: Это не очень хороший вариант :) Я бы предложил Вам более конкретно описать проблему, потому что в текущей формулировке не очень понятно, чего Вы хотите. Можете добавить больше кода, а можете написать отдельную небольшую программу, которая иллюстрирует проблему.